# Hide (or reduce size of) message headers in thunderbird when opening email

Tags: thunderbird

With larger amount of correspondents thunderbird emails messages can get really small. Is there a toggle to hide them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best solution seems to be using an add-on "[compactheader](https://github.com/jmozmoz/compactheader)". You need to give it all permissions, but it is open source and does the job pretty well:
[image]